# getting data between known patterns in a text file

Tags: perl

The below is a text file that I want process.

```
##BEGIN Text file
A . B.
DATA1
DATA12
DATA13
A  C
DATA2
DATA22
DATA23
A . B.
DATA3
DATA32
DATA33
A . B.
DATA4
DATA42
DATA43
A . B.
DATA5
DATA52
DATA53
A . B.
DATA6
DATA62
DATA63
## END text file
```

Now I would like to get the following output.

```
DATA1
DATA12
DATA13
DATA3
DATA32
DATA33
DATA4
DATA42
DATA43
DATA5
DATA52
DATA53
DATA6
DATA62
DATA63
```

I used the following perl command line but not able to get what I need. Could you tell if there is a way to achieve this in command line.

```
perl -ne 'print if(/B/.../^A/)' ~/data | grep -v ^A
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't:

```
perl -ne 'print if m/DATA/' ~/data
```

have the desired result?

The range operator you're trying to use doesn't work as well as you think, because it captures between two patterns... but does so inclusively - but I'm also not sure how well it'll handle the start and end pattern being the same line.

A quick test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   print if ( /B/ ... /^A/ );
}

__DATA__
A B
1
2
3
A B
4
5
6
A B
```

Gives:

```
A B
1
2
3
A B
A B
```

I *think* that means the first pattern is 'matching' but then the rest of the line isn't inspected for the second pattern match - it proceeds to the next line.

So looking at your data - you've got a header line, and the data you want has 'A . B' at the top (and the one you don't has 'A C').

So I think you can set `$/` to handle this:
 - `$/` is the record seperator - usually this is `\n` so a line feed, but if we set it to `\nA` we grab multi-line chunks. 
 - Then we test for the presence of `B` (Based on the above - you want stuff with a B, but not stuff with a C). 
 - and then we apply a couple of regular expressions to remove the `A . B` line. (It's a bit messier, because it's split across two chunks)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    local $/ = "\nA";
    while (<DATA>) {
        if ( m/B/ ) {
            s/\n^A$//gm;
            s/.*B\.$//gm;
            print;
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
A . B.
DATA1
DATA12
DATA13
A  C
DATA2
DATA22
DATA23
A . B.
DATA3
DATA32
DATA33
A . B.
DATA4
DATA42
DATA43
A . B.
DATA5
DATA52
DATA53
A . B.
DATA6
DATA62
DATA63
```

Gives:

```
DATA1
DATA12
DATA13
DATA3
DATA32
DATA33
DATA4
DATA42
DATA43
DATA5
DATA52
DATA53
DATA6
DATA62
DATA63
```

Which I think should do the trick?

Comment: The range operator has two forms: `..` and `...`. The two-dot form can evaluate both the begin and end expression on the same test (although it will return *true* at least once) while the three-dot form won't evaluate the range end expression until the next test. In this case the OP has used `...` so the code is safe. It's also useful to know that the value returned by the operator is a count of the number of times it has returned *true* starting at 1. The *last* time it returns *true* it has `E0` appended to the count. That makes it easy to identify the first and last items in a range.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a fiddle with a 2-dot and 3-dot range op. prints the delimiter lines, but only seems to match the group?

Comment: Sorry, saved comment half way - postin' my test code.

Comment: I suggest you create a `DATA` section with five lines containing `A`, `B X`, `C`, `D`, `E`. Then read through it with `while (<DATA>)` and use `Data::Dump` to display the value of `dd scalar(/B/ .. /X/)` and `dd scalar(/B/ ... /X/);`

Comment: Updated with what I've just tried. Looks like my 'range' only applies once.

Comment: Okay, that's because the second `A B` line switches *off* the range operator, but it isn't tested again until the next line, `4`, and so isn't turned *on* again until the *third* `A B`. You can use `..` to test the *off* condition on the same test that turns it *on*, but there's no way to do the reverse.